# Unable to disable button using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, tailwind-css

I am unable to disable submit button when someone signs up on my webpage.

```
import styles, {layout} from '../style';
import {eye, eye_hidden, google} from "../assets";
import {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {useAuth} from '../contexts/AuthContext';

const SignUp = () => {
    const {signup, currentUser} = useAuth()

    const nameRef = useRef()
    const emailRef = useRef()
    const emailConfRef = useRef()
    const pwRef = useRef()
    const pwConfRef = useRef()

    const [error, setError] = useState("")

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const [visibility_pw, setVisibility_pw] = useState(false)
    const [visibility_pwConf, setVisibility_pwConf] = useState(false)

    const handleVisibility = param => event => {
        param === "pw" ? setVisibility_pw(!visibility_pw) : setVisibility_pwConf(!visibility_pwConf)
    }

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (pwRef.current.value !== pwConfRef.current.value) {
            return setError('Passwords or Emails do not match. Please try again.')
        }

        if (emailRef.current.value !== emailConfRef.current.value) {
            return setError('Emails do not match!')
        }
        try {
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            signup(emailRef.current.value, pwRef.current.value)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error.message)
            setError('Unable to create account. Please try again')
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
    <div className={`${layout.sectionCenter} min-h-screen`}>
        <div className="bg-black/25 shadow-xl shadow-[#8F6E5D]/40 rounded-2xl p-5 min-h-full xs:w-full max-w-[800px]">
            <h2 className={`text-center mt-8 ${styles.heading4}`}>Create A New Account</h2>
            {error && 
            <div className="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative mx-8 mt-8" role="alert">
                <strong className="block sm:inline font-bold">{error}</strong>
            </div>}
            {currentUser && currentUser.email}
            <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col px-8 gap-8 mt-12">
                <input required type="text" name="name" id="name" ref={nameRef} placeholder="Enter Full Name" className="pl-2 py-2.5 rounded-lg border border-[#8F6E5D] border-opacity-75 bg-primary text-secondary" />
                <input required type="email" name="email" id="email" ref={emailRef} placeholder="Enter Email" className="pl-2 py-2.5 rounded-lg border border-[#8F6E5D] border-opacity-75 bg-primary text-secondary" />
                <input required type="email" name="email_conf" id="email_conf" ref={emailConfRef} placeholder="Confirm Email" className="pl-2 py-2.5 rounded-lg border border-[#8F6E5D] border-opacity-75 bg-primary text-secondary" />
                <div className="relative">
                    <input required type={visibility_pw ? "text" : "password"} name="password" id="password" ref={pwRef} placeholder="Enter Password" className="pl-2 py-2.5 rounded-lg border border-[#8F6E5D] border-opacity-75 bg-primary w-full text-secondary" />
                    <img onClick={handleVisibility("pw")} src={visibility_pw ? eye_hidden : eye} alt="toggle password visibility" className={`${visibility_pw ? "h-[20px]" : "h-[65%]"} pw_visibility absolute top-[50%] right-5 -translate-y-[50%] cursor-pointer`} />
                </div>
                <div className="relative">
                    <input required type={visibility_pwConf ? "text" : "password"} name="password_conf" id="password_conf" ref={pwConfRef} placeholder="Confirm Password" className="pl-2 py-2.5 rounded-lg border border-[#8F6E5D] border-opacity-75 bg-primary w-full text-secondary" />
                    <img onClick={handleVisibility("pw_conf")} src={visibility_pwConf ? eye_hidden : eye} alt="toggle confirm password visibility" className={`${visibility_pwConf ? "h-[20px]" : "h-[65%]"} pw_visibility absolute top-[50%] right-5 -translate-y-[50%] cursor-pointer`} />
                </div>
                <button disabled={loading} type="submit" className={`py-2 px-6 font-playfairDisplay font-medium text-[18px] outline-none rounded-lg ${loading ? "bg-gradient-to-r from-[#8F6E5D]/50 to-[#7E4F43]/50 text-dimWhite/50" : "bg-gradient-to-r from-[#8F6E5D] to-[#7E4F43] text-white"} ${loading ? "" : styles.buttonHover} mx-auto mt-4`}>Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            <div className="mt-12 grid grid-cols-3 px-8 items-center">
                <hr className="opacity-25"/>
                <p className={`${styles.paragraph} text-center text-md`}>OR</p>
                <hr className="opacity-25"/>
            </div>
            <button type="button" className="bg-white border py-2 px-4 mt-8 mb-12 mx-auto rounded-lg flex justify-center items-center text-center hover:scale-95 duration-300">
                <img src={google} alt="google icon" className="h-[32px] w-[32px]" />
                <p className="ml-3">Sign up with Google</p>
            </button>
            <div className="flex justify-between px-8 mt-4 mb-8">
                <p className={`${styles.paragraph} text-sm sm:text-lg`}>Have an account?</p>
                <button type="button" className="hover:scale-90 duration-300 hover:text-[#8F6E5D] hover:from-[#FAF6F5] hover:to-[#FAF6F5] hover:ease-in-out cursor-pointer py-1 px-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-[#8F6E5D] to-[#7E4F43] font-playfairDisplay font-medium text-[18px] text-white outline-none rounded-lg">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default SignUp
```

Under the button, `disabled={loading}` does not work. I was however able to give an illusion of button being disabled when I created a `const isDisabled=true` and used it in the button like the following:

```
<button disabled={loading} type="submit" className={`py-2 px-6 font-playfairDisplay font-medium text-[18px] outline-none rounded-lg ${isDisabled ? "bg-gradient-to-r from-[#8F6E5D]/50 to-[#7E4F43]/50 text-dimWhite/50" : "bg-gradient-to-r from-[#8F6E5D] to-[#7E4F43] text-white"} ${isDisabled ? "" : styles.buttonHover} mx-auto mt-4`}>Sign Up</button>
```

However, the style is still not exactly dynamic as when I click on the submit the button still does not become disabled, as it keeps to the original value of isDisabled.

I cannot understand what is missing as I have tried various methods.

Comment: Can you please share the full code for that component?

Comment: Edited the code to include the full code @MuhammadHaseeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working as expected because you used `setLoading(false)` right after the catch body and the state after the code is completly runs so it is just setting the false again in order to fix this issue use the `finnaly` like:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (pwRef.current.value !== pwConfRef.current.value) {
            return setError('Passwords or Emails do not match. Please try again.')
        }

        if (emailRef.current.value !== emailConfRef.current.value) {
            return setError('Emails do not match!')
        }
        try {
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            signup(emailRef.current.value, pwRef.current.value)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error.message)
            setError('Unable to create account. Please try again')
        } finally {
        setLoading(false)
        }
    }
```

hopfully it will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using `await` in   `signup(emailRef.current.value, pwRef.current.value)`.

and because you are not using await isLoading set true and immediately false.

**Correct Code :**

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (pwRef.current.value !== pwConfRef.current.value) {
            return setError('Passwords or Emails do not match. Please try again.')
        }

        if (emailRef.current.value !== emailConfRef.current.value) {
            return setError('Emails do not match!')
        }
        try {
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await signup(emailRef.current.value, pwRef.current.value)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error.message)
            setError('Unable to create account. Please try again')
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }
```

let me know if it work

Comment: if it not work, can you share `useAuth`  from `../contexts/AuthContext`.